# Which RAM to buy?

Tags: laptop, memory

On my laptop I have 16 GB of RAM. I see that it supports up to 32 GB and I have to increase it.

The technical details of the RAM already present is as follows:

```
$ sudo dmidecode --type memory
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.1 present.

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000E
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 16 GB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2667 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 2D178A3E
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: ACR26D4S9D8ME-16    
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 2667 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.25 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.35 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000E
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: Unknown
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Memory Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown
```

I was thinking to buy a RAM module from Amazon and mount it myself on my laptop.

Can I do it?

Which module do I have to buy?

I need to increase my RAM to the maximum possible level.

Please specify which commands do I need to run and report if you need more technical details about my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, in short it is possible and I do recommend upgrading the RAM of your laptop since it is one of the cheapest yet effective ways to increase its performance. Details provided above indicate to me that there is a slot empty to insert another RAM stick to perfectly increase it to the maximum 32 GB limit of the motherboard. It will be beneficial especially in applications involving video editing, 3D rendering, audio editing or if you have an AMD CPU(since AMD CPU's are observed to perform significantly better when paired with faster ram).

Coming to the purchase, although in theory it is possible to mix and match between the brands and the speeds(frequency) and buy the cheapest/most expensive(with additional features) one, it's not recommended. The **same form factor**(DDR3, DDR4, etc) and **same voltage** RAM can be used together. However, for the best system performance it is advised to use RAM sticks by the same manufacturer, of the same size and of the same frequency. This is mainly to avoid bottlenecks in bandwidth during communication and thus ensures maximum throughput in the 'dual channel' mode of operation.
Details suggest to me that this is the RAM module you are running:
Brand :             Kingston
Part Number :       ACR26D4S9D8ME-16
Interface :         SODIMM
Size :              16384 MB(16 GB)
Type :              DDR4
Speed :             2667 MHz
Total width :       64 bits
(Please verify the same by looking up your laptop model on the web, the specifications sheet will provide you with the exact details of the RAM stick installed). Purchase the RAM stick following these specifications from the website/store of your choice.

Once you have purchased the appropriate RAM it is time to install it. Application steps are as simple as :

1. Ensure your laptop is powered off.
2. Unscrew the backplate of the laptop (and carefully store the screws aside).
3. Find the empty SODIMM slot (usually adjacent to the occupied bay).
4. Insert the RAM stick carefully into the slot until you hear a satisfying click. Usually inserted at an angle and then pushed down gently.
   **NOTE:** RAM sticks go in only one way so align the notch of the RAM with the one on the motherboard to ensure proper insertion. Observe the orientation of the pre-existing stick to give you an idea.
5. Verify it has been installed in the UEFI boot menu(toggled by pressing F2 at boot). If not detected patiently re-install the same or consult a technician.
   I suggest you google how to install RAM in your specific laptop. Video tutorials will give you a clear idea. If not your laptop, there are videos for other laptops as well which I recommend you watch before proceeding with the installation.

Hope this helps and don't forget to have fun.

Additional Read: To get maximum use out of your memory I suggest you read about overclocking your RAM(i.e **enabling XMP**).In brief it basically toggles your RAM to a higher operational frequency thus providing higher performance at no extra cost however might decrease the long term durability due to additional heat produced.

Comment: Thank you very much. You suggest to buy 2 modules of 16 GB each and substitute the existing module also. (1) How do I find out if the already existing module is soldered in the motherboard? (2) If I substitute both modules, can I increase the frequency from 2666 MT/s and buy something faster? Or the motherboard won't support it?

Comment: Quick clarification:
I suggested buying only one extra RAM stick that is identical to the pre-existing one(same brand, frequency etc.) for the upgrade.
OR
Do the additional research to find out the maximum voltage and frequency supported by the motherboard present in your laptop and accordingly buy 2 RAM sticks of higher performance. You would have to enable XMP as well to obtain the higher clock speeds you desire(elaborated in 'Additional Read' section above).

Clearly, the former solution is the more cost-effective however the latter should result in better performance.

Comment: The only way to surely check if the RAM is not sortered on is by opening the back panel and surveying, else a simpler way is to check your laptops specifications sheet if they mention anything about RAM replacement. It is a common practice where if the manufacturer does not want upgradability does not provide an additional slot in the first place. Since your data above does indicates there is a free slot, my gut instinct is that your RAM is not soldered on and hence upgradable. Your laptop name and model number would be helpful for me to address further queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but if you don't use 90+% of your ram, it should not impact performance. You should buy a 16GB stick (or a 1*16GB kit) with a 2667Mhz speed. To make it fit in the socket, use DDR4 SODIMM. To ensure the best compatibility, try buying the same stick that is already in your laptop (google Kingston ACR26D4S9D8ME-16). To install the ram stick, you can use the instructions given by @MANAV of see if the laptop manufacturer has a video explaining how you can upgrade the ram. If your laptop allows to, also enable XMP or DOCP to get a little extra performance

Comment: Unfortunately the exact same model `Kingston ACR26D4S9D8ME-16` is not on Amazon and I don't know where to buy it ....

Comment: Yes, I need the extra RAM for numerical analysis. The current setup have the RAM saturated and the swap file ALMOST saturated. So I think with the RAM increase I would be able to carry out the analysis

Comment: I think the one at https://www.amazon.com/Kingston-16GB-DDR4-2666MHZ-SODIMM/dp/B07D2DZ42B is good enough